# IntelliJ IDEA upgrade dependencies feature is missing

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

In IntelliJ IDEA there is the following feature:

> *IntelliJ IDEA will show the suggestion to upgrade when we hover over the dependency, and we can click the suggestion to upgrade the dependencies.* ([source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/managing-dependencies/update-dependencies/))

[image: Screenshot of the upgrade feature]

This feature always worked for me until a few days ago.

Now the dependencies are not marked with squiggly lines underneath them when an update is available. Also in the [dependencies tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/dependencies-analysis.html) the update feature is not available anymore.

How can I restore this feature?

Comment: It's a known problem. Please follow for updates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PKGS-1026/Dependencies-tool-windows-no-longer-suggest-dependency-upgrade